# Kairos API: Face Recognition Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, api

what the basic Face Recognition algorithms used in Kairos API, whether it Eigenface, fishereye, neural networks or others?
I ask this for educational purposes, please for the answer and thanks

Answer (score 1):

Kairos doesn't publish which algorithms / techniques are used as part of its service. This is for a variety of reasons including confidentiality with some of our parters, and more importantly that what we use is always subject to change / improvement over time, so it wouldn't be prudent to memorialize a SO answer with potentially out of date information.

- Source: I am CTO of [Kairos.com](https://www.kairos.com)

Comment: but to be honest I have found kairos recognition very accurate and its better than microsoft, google and amazon recognition.